# Besides Muhammad, who else claim that they are prophets around his time and place?

Tags: prophets

I've heard that there are many "copycats". They claim they are prophets too. Of course, anyone can claim they are prophets. They have many followers too.

Who are they?

Any lists?

Anyone compile lists of them?

I am not questioning whether they are false prophets or not. I am questioning whether they claim they are prophets and whether people believe them.

Answer (score 4):

The false prophets who arose around the time of Prophet Muhammad(p.b.u.h), in Arabia include:

1. [Musailmah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musaylimah)
2. [Sajjah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sajah)
3. [Tulayha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulayha)
4. [Aswad Ansi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Aswad_Al-Ansi)

Details about them can probably be best sourced from books of Seerah and the histories of Abu Bakr's caliphate. None of these have any surviving cults as the claimants were either slain in battle or reverted to Islam.

Comment: And Saf ibn Sayyad-later known as Abdullah ibn Sa'id

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Muhammad, who else claims to be a prophet in his time and place?
Musallamah ibn Habib, known as "Masilmah al-Kadhab", was one of the false prophets who claimed to be a prophet at the end of the Prophet's life. [1] In addition to him, Taliyah among Bani Assad, [2] Aswad Ansi in Yemen [3] and Sajjah among Bani Tamim [4] claimed to be prophets.

Masilemeh, who falsely claimed to be a partner in the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH), wrote in a letter to the Messenger of God (PBUH): "I have shared with you in the matter of prophethood. So half of the earth is from you and half from me. But the Quraysh are a violent people. [16] The letter of Muslimah was brought to the Messenger of God (PBUH) by two of his messengers. The Imam asked them what they thought about Muslim. They said that our opinion is the same as what is written in this letter. The Prophet (pbuh) said: "I swear by God, if it were not disgusting for the messengers to be killed, I would be beheading you now." [17]
Then that Imam wrote in the reply letter of Muslimah:

From Muhammed, the Messenger of God, to a Muslim, a liar, the land belongs to God, and He inherits it from whomever He wills of His servants, and the outcome is for the righteous.”[18]
From Muhammad, the Messenger of God (PBUH) to the false Muslim, the earth belongs to God and he inherits it to whomever he wants from his servants, and in the end it is good for the pious.
Then the Holy Prophet (PBUH) said to the Muslims: "Curse him so that his God may curse him." [19]
Muhammad (PBUH) is the Prophet of God and not only after him there is no prophet with whom any other prophet is not a partner.

> [1]. Tabari, Muhammad bin Jarir; The History of al-Tabari, translated
> by Abu al-Qasim Bayandeh, Tehran, Asateer, 1375, Najm, vol. 4, p. 1266
> and Yaqubi, Ibn Wadeh; The History of Yaqubi, translated by Muhammad
> Ibrahim Aity, Tehran, Scientific and Farangi publications, 1371,
> Shisham, vol. 2, p. 7. [2]. Ibn Atheer, Ezzedine; Asad al-Ghaba,
> Beirut, Dar al-Fikr, 1409, vol. 1, p. 450 and Tabari, pishin, vol. 4,
> p. 1274. [3]. Tabari, Pishin, vol. 4 pp. 1355-1354. [4]. Ibn Atheer,
> Peshin, vol. 4 pg. 277 and Asqalani, Ibn Hajar; Al-Isbah fi
> distinguishing the Companions, Beirut, Dar Al-Kutub Al-Ilmiyya, Awal,
> 1415, vol. 2, p. 181 and Tabari, Pishin, vol. 4, p. 1396. [16]. Ibn
> Hisham, PIshin, vol. 2, p. 327, and Yacoubi, pishin, vol. 2, p. 7, and
> Tabari, pishin, vol. 4, p. 1273. [17]. Ibn Hisham, PIshin, vol. 2, p.
> 327, and Tabari, pishin, vol. 4, p. 1273. [18]. Yacoubi, Pishin, vol.
> 2, p. 7 and Tabari, pishin, vol. 4, p. 1273. [19]. Baladhari, Ahmed
> bin Yahya; Ansab Al-Ashraf, Beirut, Dar Al-Fikr, 1417, Awal, Part 4,
> p. 293.